# vim function for toggling colorschemes

Tags: vim

At the moment I'm using two different keys to toogle the colorscheme

```
map <F8> :colors wombat256 <cr>
map <F9> :colors dimtag <cr>
```

I want to achieve a toggle behavior like this

```
function! ToggleDimTags()
if (g:colors_name == "wombat256")
  colors dimtag
else
  colors wombat256
endif
endfunction
```

My problem is that `ToogleDimTags()` is resetting the cursor position to the first line on every call, which is undesirable.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the `:map` command you're using to call `ToggleDimTags()`?  I suspect that might be the root cause.

Comment: @Conspicuous Compiler map <F5> :exe ToggleDimTags() <cr> and returns to the first line too

Comment: Try `:call ToggleDimTags()<CR>`. @Conspicuous Compiler, please add it as an answer if it works.

Comment: That worked @sidyll, add it so I can set it to answered

Comment: @sidyll: please add your comment as an answer so that Eric can accept it.

Comment: @Eric Fortis & @yoda: thanks but I'd feel bad doing it. @Conspicuous Compiler gave the clue to this, so I'd prefer to see his answer as accepted. Let's wait a bit until he logs in again.

Comment: @Eric Fortis: If you are interested `:exe ToggleDimTags()` variant does the same as `:call ToggleDimTags()<CR>:0<CR>` because functions that end not with explicit `:return` statements return 0. `:exe` takes function value and executes it and `:<lineNumber>` is one of the ways to move cursor to given line. `0` is an alias to `1` in this case (line numbering starts with `1`).

Comment: By the way, it is better to write `:nnoremap` here. `n` is because you probably don't need this mapping in operator-pending mode and you definitely don't need it in visual mode (as it will execute ToggleDimTags as much times as number of selected lines). `nore` because it will make mapping immune to things like another mapping swapping meanings of `:` and `;` for convenience.

Comment: Ok, timeout. Otherwise this may become a un-answered question for indeterminate time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is that your map calling `:execute`
behaves a little differently, what you probably want is `:call` instead:

```
nnoremap <F5> :call ToggleDimTags()
```

To clarify what @ZyX was saying, `:h :exec` contains the following text:

```
                                                         :exe   :execute 
:exe[cute] {expr1} ..   Executes the string that results from the evaluation
                        of {expr1} as an Ex command.
                        [...]
```

So what `:execute` really does is evaluating the expression looking for a string
that will be executed as an Ex command (also called colon commands). In other words:

```
exec ToggleDimTags() | " <-- ToggleDimTags() is evaluated and returns 0
exec 0
```

Which is:

```
:0
```

Now, `:h :call`:

```
                                                 :cal   :call   E107   E117 
:[range]cal[l] {name}([arguments])
                Call a function.  The name of the function and its arguments
                are as specified with |:function|.  Up to 20 arguments can be
                used.  **The returned value is discarded**.
                [...]
```

---

#### Update

I've been thinking about your function, and using the ternary operator and a bit
of `:execute` magic, you can simplify it up to a point where you discard the extra
function:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F9> :exec "color " .
    \ ((g:colors_name == "wombat256") ? "dimtag" : "wombat256")<CR>
```

Here, this *nnoremap* will not produce output (`<silent>`) and is based on
`:exec`, which is followed by this expression:

```
"color " . ((g:colors_name == "wombat256") ? "dimtag" : "wombat256")
```

When `g:colors_name` is set to `wombat256`, the expression evaluates to:

```
"color dimtag"
```

Or, otherwise:

```
"color wombat256"
```

Then either one is evaluated by `:exec`. Of course you can join the lines
(without forgetting to remove the backslash), I did it like this simply to avoid
a too long line.

Comment: Excellent summary.  Glad you added it.

Comment: Aha! @Conspicuous Compiler found :-) I hope you don't mind, but I took your place in posting this answer while adding a bit of bibliography.

Comment: @Eric Fortis, I just updated the answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Don't mind at all.  You added more than I did in the comments, and your answer is far more helpful than mine would have been.  Cheers!